# Browser changing the markup and breaking my CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have in a foreach loop:

```
echo "<span style=\"" . myCss($value) . "\">lol</span>";
```

Which turns into (in source):

```
<span style="">lol</span>color: #999999;background-color: transparent;font-weight:normal;text-decoration: none;<span style="">...
```

Why? how to prevent the browser? Same for Chrome and Firefox. Note there is a reason for it being in-line, an I want to avoid doing it via javascript.

Comment: Are you looking at it from the web inspector? It shows the parsed structure of the DOM, not the original source. Do a view source and see what's printed out by the server

Comment: How does the `myCss()` method end? `return`, `print` or `echo`?

Comment: Im viewing source. The sting appears on screen.

Comment: @WillemLabu I have tried both return and echo. Going to try print.

Comment: Please add the exact output of `myCss($value)` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo "<span style='" . myCss($value) . "'>lol</span>";
```

Comment: The output is the same unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

How about a little separation of PHP and HTML:

```
<span style="<?php echo myCss($value); ?>">lol</span>
```

Notice I encapsulate the PHP within the quotes, rather than `echo` the entire line. In a foreach loop it would look something like:

```
<?php
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
?>

<span style="<?php echo myCss($value); ?>">lol</span>

<?php
    }
?>
```

This separation of PHP and HTML has been the standard practice everywhere that I have worked, and I personally find it to be much more transparent.

Comment: The function iterates through a number of times. Inteded to create a number of spans.

Comment: @OBV - I updated my answer to show how to do it with a `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your function and the values of the variables, I an only assume that there are characters in the echoed result that mess up the html. You should always use [`htmlspecialschars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when you output to html:

```
echo "<span style=\"" . htmlspecialschars(myCss($value)) . "\">lol</span>";
```

Although you would probably use it in your function.

Comment: Tried but alas same result. Will try and show more code